# Is it possible for a dependency to create a database table in elixir?

Tags: elixir, metaprogramming, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to build a simple auth system in elixir/phoenix that can be used as a dependency in any phoenix application.

I have followed the steps taken in the `programming-phoenix-1.4` book and set up a basic auth system easily enough.

In this book they talk about separating a users sensitive and non-sensitive information into different places in the application and database. All the non-sensitive info (username, name, etc) is put in the `users` table while the sensitive info (email, password, etc) is put in the `credentials` table.

Based on this, I wondered if it would be possible to separate out the auth logic into its own application.

This auth module will need to:

1. create a `credentials` table in the database of the requiring application
2. update said table based on info passed from the parent app
3. contain an `auth plug` capable of updating the `conn` from the parent application (for example adding `:current_user` to the `conn` with the `assign` function)

Unfortunately I am falling at the first hurdle at the moment. I am not sure if it is possible to require a module that can create a database table.

I imagine that if step 1 is possible step 2 will be straightforward. Step 3 looks like it can be achieved with the [Router.forward/4](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html#forward/4) function.

Comment: I am not sure what is that book mentioned, but I hardly understand the reasons or splitting user info into two separate tables. Also, how this module you propose would be better than battle-proved `Guardian`?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Thanks a lot for your response (and for all your other responses to elixir questions). I was mostly using this as a learning experience and wanted to know if this idea would be possible for me to build. I thought it would help create a simple signup/login/logout flow in any app I build following the lessons from programming phx 1.4. My goal wasn't to build something that I would use over something like `Guardian` in a "real" project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible by giving the dependency the name of the repo module. An example of this is `GuardianDB` that creates a table to store valid tokens. The configuration for GuardianDB looks like this:

```
config :guardian, Guardian.DB,
  repo: MyApp.Repo,
  # default
  schema_name: "guardian_tokens",
  # default: 60 minutes
  sweep_interval: 60
```

you can use that library as a guide [github](https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian_db)

As for creating plugs, `Guardian`, which is an authentication library for Elixir does, that too. You can find the code [here](https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian)